# Angular HTTP Get call falls into infinite loop

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Hi I am developing web application in Angular 5. I am developing tree structure in Angular 5. I am making http get call to get child nodes. I am able to get child nodes but api is going to infinite loop. It never stops. Below is my implementation.

```
 getChildren(node: any) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.nodeservice.GetNodes().subscribe((data: any) => {
                const newNodes = data.map((c) => Object.assign({}, c));
                setTimeout(() => resolve(newNodes), 1000);
            });
        });
    }
```

Below is my service call.

```
public GetNodes() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/jsonresponse.json');
    }
```

May I know what I am missing in the above code? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Whats wrong with returning observable?

Answer (score -1):

No need to return a new promise from your subscription, just have your service Observable become a promise using .toPromise()

So in your service, "nodeService" rather, getNodes() would use the httpClient or http from angular to create an Observable and then you promisfy that.

HttpClient:

```
this.http.get().toPromise()
```

Http:

```
   return this.http.get(this.data, v)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

and then in your component or wheverever you subscribe, you are getting a promise so use then(). Don't forget to change any method sigs return value to Promise if you are using toPromise().

ex:

```
  getNodes(): Promise<any>
```

Your Component: Remove the new promise, and instead of subscribe use then()

```
getChildren(node: any) {
        this.nodeservice.GetNodes().then((data: any) => {
            const newNodes = data.map((c) => Object.assign({}, c));
            setTimeout(() => resolve(newNodes), 1000);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to   return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/jsonresponse.json').toPromise(); and started to get error  this.nodeservice.GetNodes(...).subscribe is not a function

Comment: Are you using httpClient or Http? if http, then this.http.get().map(response => { do something with response }).toPromise();

Comment: I am using http. I have added my service code above.

Comment: it should return promise/observable and you should be able to subscribe to it, i've updated my answer

Comment: so i should change my service or component?

Comment: service: such as

   return this.http.get(this.categoryURL, v)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);

Comment: I am using private http: HttpClient in constructor.

Comment: okay, add .toPromise() to your service, and thenr emove the new Promise( from your component in getChildren method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176741/discussion-between-niranjan-and-taranjit-kang).